# sdk inside iOS framework swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, frameworks

I'm new on iOS and i don't understand somethings.

First, I need to make a library as in Android. So it is correct to make a cocoa touch framework?
So i have this project structure :

[image: project ios]

Next, i need to import this sdk to use it inside my framework.
https://github.com/kontaktio/kontakt-ios-sdk

But i don't find how to import this one. I have try to drag and drop the KontaktSdk.framework inside the ..._library but i have this error when i run my app :
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/KontaktSDK.framework/KontaktSDK
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7A74722F-D2C5-49F2-BC77-955B90B1A421/..._app.app/Frameworks/..._library.framework/..._library
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)

I have tried to follow this instruction: 
[image: Kontakt sdk]

But in the framework, i don't have the "Embedded Binaries" section.

I hope you can help me =)
Thanks

Comment: yes it is cocoa touch framework. also try to use [cocoapods](https://github.com/kontaktio/kontakt-ios-sdk#cocoapods) for importing

Comment: Try using [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/) to include kontakt. CocoaPods will do a lot of work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use CocoaPods.

You need to embed KontaktSdk.framework in your application's build phase. Since your library's output is not an .app bundle, it does not have a /Frameworks directory inside it. That's why it does not have a "Embed Framework" build phase.

You should link KontaktSdk.framework framework against your _library, but embed KontaktSdk.framework into your application target.

Comment: So if i have understood, i need to link the kontaktSDK in the app (as described in the doc) and i can use it in my framework? But it means that all dev who use my framework to make they own app need to add this framework to their app to use my framework? It is right?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to ship other frameworks and your customers need to embed them themselves. Or you could request a static kontaktSDK from vendor and link it against you library. There is an "umbrella framework" concept btw. But it's highly discorouraged on macOS (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html), and apparently impossible on iOS (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2435/_index.html).